# PostgreSQL - When creating a view use columns that are being created in SELECT to create another column in the same view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create view from few tables
lets say i have
table1 (t1)

```
ID | Time_of_start | Duration
```

table2 (t2)

```
time_of_login | time_of_logout | Name
```

and i created a view lets call it wwn

```
t1.ID | t1.Time_of_start | Time_of_end(t1.Time_of_start + t1.Duration) | Name
```

```
CREATE VIEW wwn
AS SELECT ID, 
Time_of_start , 
(Time_of_start  + Duration * interval '1 minute') as Time_of_end, 
Duration, 
(select name from table2, wwn where (time_of_login, time_of_logout) overlaps (Time_of_start, Time_of_end))
FROM table1 where ID = 300;
```

and that doesn't work because there is no wwn when this is executed, the only thing i can think of is creating other temporary view.
So i need a name to represent who was logined at the time of  event between Time_of_start, Time_of_end

Samples

```
table1 
300 | 2019-07-25 09:13:40 | 20 
300 | 2019-07-25 09:33:40 | 30
table2
2019-07-25 07:13:40 | 2019-07-25 19:32:37 | Anthon
2019-07-25 20:32:37 | 2019-07-26 10:14:20 | John
```

Desired Result

```
wwn
300 | 2019-07-25 09:13:40 | 2019-07-25 09:33:40 | 20 | Anthon
300 | 2019-07-25 09:33:40 | 2019-07-25 10:03:40 | 30 | Anthon
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with views, the SELECT alone will raise the same error. In a SELECT list, you can simply not refer column aliases defined in the same SELECT list.

Comment: First try to create a select query which will give you desired results. Once that is done..just create view on that.

Comment: And a view can't select from itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test case (fiddle):

[Working test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=407ca3e6dc7a0fc3f8027a4f683f788a)

Just use a `WITH` clause term (or derived table) to handle the duration calculation, then use that in the subsequent expression.

Just the query (no view):

```
WITH cte1 AS (
        SELECT t1.ID, t1.Time_of_start
             , (t1.Time_of_start + t1.Duration * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) AS Time_of_end
             , Duration
          FROM table1 AS t1
     )
SELECT cte1.*, name
  FROM cte1
  JOIN table2
    ON (time_of_login, time_of_logout) overlaps (Time_of_start, Time_of_end)
;
```

From that, just create the view:

```
CREATE VIEW wwm AS
WITH cte1 AS (
        SELECT t1.ID, t1.Time_of_start
             , (t1.Time_of_start + t1.Duration * INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) AS Time_of_end
             , Duration
          FROM table1 AS t1
     )
SELECT cte1.*, name
  FROM cte1
  JOIN table2
    ON (time_of_login, time_of_logout) overlaps (Time_of_start, Time_of_end)
;
```

Comment: Can I use multiple WITH?

Comment: @SL07 Sure.  The `WITH` clause terms are comma separated.  `WITH cte1 AS (...), cte2 AS (...) SELECT ... FROM cte1 JOIN cte2 ON ... etc...;`  This can be almost as complex as you need, and supports recursive behavior. `WITH` clause terms can refer to any prior `WITH` clause term, including themselves (with recursive behavior).